# trigger direct onchanger with another file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, input

I want to crop the photo and then place it directly into my existing input, since I use a barcode reading library, the onchange state must be triggered directly for it to work.

```js
  document.getElementById("html5-qrcode-anchor-scan-type-change")?.click();
    let fileButton = document.getElementById(
      "html5-qrcode-button-file-selection"
    ) as HTMLInputElement | undefined;
    let fileInput = document.getElementById(
      "html5-qrcode-private-filescan-input"
    ) as HTMLInputElement | undefined;
    if (fileButton) {
      fileButton.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (fileInput) {
      fileInput.style.display = "block";
      fileInput.addEventListener(
        "change",
        (e) => {
          //??
        },
        false
      );
    }
```

When I select the photo directly in the input, it works.
When I say file input.files=cropImage, it shows selected in the input but the operation is not triggered.
how can I trigger this situation?

thanks.

Comment: Create a function, put that operations in it and then call it in both direct input and programmatic input.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I solved the problem

```
fileInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```